# Enable button C#

Tags: c#, button, parent

I have an user control calling a method on my main form and this method should enable a button (by default this button is disabled) on the same form, but it's not working.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 fr = new Form1();
        fr.login(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
    }
```

And here is my method

```
 public void login(string username, string password)
    {
        Connect();
        sendMessage("LoginAction,Username=" + username + "UserPassword=" + password);
    }
```

Here is where the button is enabled

```
private void commandInterpreter(string Message)
    {
        if(Message.Contains("LoginSuccess,") == true)
        {
            name = Message.Remove(Message.IndexOf("LoginSuccess,Name="), 18);
            Bt2En = true;
        }
    }
```

Here is where I'm exposing my button properties:

```
public bool Bt2En
    {
        get { return button2.Enabled; }
        set { button2.Enabled = value; }
    }
```

Comment: You seem to be creating a new instance of Form1 and enabling the button on that instance.  If you expect the button on the original instance to be affected you need to call it on the correct instance.

Comment: I've tried it before and unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried calling `login` on `this` instead of `new Form1`? That seems to me like it should be the flow you want.  If that isn't working you may have larger architectural problems to overcome first.

Comment: We cannot see the code of sendMessage, but why do you send _LoginAction,_ and then search for _LoginSuccess,_?

Comment: @Steve it's my server response to LoginAction, no problems with this one (fortunately)

Comment: @BradleyUffner yes, I've also tried this one

Comment: Did you try to debug this code? Place breakpoints and check if the code follows the path expected.

Comment: @Steve yes, as you can see here (http://goo.gl/f8qsNA) it changes the value of the property but my button is still disabled.

Comment: So, this code is part of Form1 class. Now if you look at the first comment I think you have the solution. This code executes on a different instance of the form1 not on the one that you expect. Try to call _fr.Show()_ before the call to fr.login and I bet you could see the disabled button on the wrong instance of Form1

Comment: @Steve hmm, I saw it now, how do I do it on the current instance?

Comment: If the code of button1_click is executed from the first instance of Form1 then you could try to use _this.login(textbox1.Text, textbox2.Text);_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem doing this, these are my methods from Form1:

```
public void login()
    {
        Connect();
        Login lg = this.lg;
        string username = lg.Username;
        string password = lg.Password;
        MessageBox.Show(username + "\n" + password);
    }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        login();
    }
```

And this one is from my user control:

```
public string Username
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
    }
    public string Password
    {
        get { return textBox2.Text; }
    }
```

Thanks Steve and Bradley Uffner for help and everyone who tried. I'm posting the answer for who has the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Bt2En is a property but You use such as methods.

```
public void bt2En(bool flag)
{
if(flag)
button.Enable=true;
}
```

Comment: So, how should I use it?

Comment: How is it being used as a method?

Comment: If that was true then it would be a compiler error.

Comment: Sorry but this is not going to work, it's the same as I use button.Enable = true in my login method, unfortunately it's not that simple.